# ExtJS 4.2 - Constrained window is not positioned correctly after maximizing and then restoring

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, position, extjs4.2

I have a window inside a panel with `constrainHeader:true` and `maximizable:true`.  I'm using ExtJS 4.2.1.883.  When the window is maximized, it expands to fill the panel as expected.  When the window is restored, however, it does not return to it's previous position and is instead positioned slightly higher than expected.

See jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kE2HB/).

To reproduce, click the 'add window' button, maximize the window, and then restore it.  I expect that this issue is due to the header and/or toolbar but am not sure how to accommodate for that.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to this issue.  I appreciate your response (hence the up vote) but merely informing me that this is a bug is not really answering my question.

Comment: have you tried adding a restore listener like a user suggested in the thread: win.on('restore', function (win) {
    Ext.defer(function () {
        // Recalcualte position...    
    }, 1);
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just overriding the maximize method for Ext.window.Window.  There's a line where the window calculates the position it should be restored to.  I changed that as follows:

```
//me.restorePos = me.getPosition(true);
me.restorePos = me.getPosition();
```

From the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-method-getPosition):

> getPosition( [local] ) : Number[] Gets the current XY position of the
>   component's underlying element.
>
> Available since: 4.0.0
>
> Parameters local : Boolean (optional) If true the element's left and
>   top are returned instead of page XY.
>
> Defaults to: false

This may cause different issues in some situations, but I have not noticed any problems in my application so I'm going with it for now.  Updated jsFiddle with full override [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aQda3/).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a bug with recalculating the size of the containing box. Every time you maximize and restore it shifts the window up by the height of the toolbar of the containing panel.

Oh and a confirmed bug case here: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?266726